# Pointing of variables in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I create a function `A` that is used as an argument in another function, so `B(A)`. Function `A` points to an entry in a (SciPy) array `C`. If I change the array `C` from within `B`, then the value in the array will be changed globally, so that also `A` notices that change. Here is an example:

```
def pointing_test2(inputs, fs):
    local = inputs
    print (local is initial)
    print fs(0)
    local[0] += 1.0
    print fs(0)

initial = sc.array([1.0])
func = lambda x: initial[0]

pointing_test2(initial, func)

------- Output -------
True
1.0
2.0
[ 2.]
```

One can avoid that the array `C` is changed globally by making a copy locally within `B`, like so:

```
[...]
        local = inputs.copy()
[...]

------- Output -------
False
1.0
1.0
[ 1.]
```

What I want to achieve is midway! I would like to have the function `A` to point to the copy of the array locally, so within `B`! In that fashion, the output I desire would be the following:

```
------- Output -------
False
1.0
2.0
[ 1.]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide some background for your real case application? Because there seems to be something quite not right with the code you're showing.

Comment: I'm glad to do so, I updated my question. Let me know whether you think that is still suited to this question. If not, it would be great if you could point me to a relevant forum!

Comment: Why would you need a pointing function for that? Can't you just do copies of the indermediate vectors, store them (or only the info that you'll need) and go on with your algorithm?

Comment: If I would taylor the alogrithm to my purpose - no problem. If I want to write a general algorithm, that's where the trouble starts! Maybe the solution is to find another formulation of the set of equations...

Comment: What do you mean by general algorithm? I fear that continuing discussing this here will be off topic. Would you continue in chat?

Comment: Ok, I'll remove the backgruond again since it seems confusing. Still I think some other people might have the same question in the future, so it's still relevant. Maybe there are some applications to it so I'll leave it around.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8927/discussion-between-thomas-and-rik-poggi)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to write A so that B passes it the array to work on (hence: the locally modified one). Is there any reason you don't want to do that?

```
def func(arr):
    return arr[0]
```

(Incidentally your `func` ignores its argument).